# Zariski topology and polynomial maps

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I've read on my book that Zariski topology is coarser than every topology in which polynomial maps are continous, but no proof of this fact is given. Could someone sketch me the proof of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It suffices to prove that, in any topology where polynomial maps are continuous, the Zariski-closed subsets are closed. So suppose $X$ is an algebraic set with such a topology and let $Y \subseteq X$ be Zariski-closed. Then there must exist polynomials $f_1, \ldots, f_r$ such that $Y = X \cap V (f_1, \ldots, f_r)$, and
$$V (f_1, \ldots, f_r) = V (f_1) \cap \cdots \cap V (f_r)$$
but $V (f) = f^{-1} \{ 0 \}$, and $\{ 0 \}$ is a closed subset of $k$, so $Y$ is indeed closed.

Note that we are assuming that points in $k$ are closed subsets – but this is a reasonable hypothesis.